# strategy to install ubuntu and dual-boot it with existing winxp

Tags: multi-boot, grub

I have a laptop with winxp already installed on it, and I am considering what is the best strategy to install Ubuntu and dual-boot. I am familiar with the procedure to shrink the winxp partition and install Ubuntu on the second partition (as outlined here, I performed this a few times already). However, I am still not sure about the following problem:

1. Can I, over time, shrink the Windows partition and enlarge (leftward) the Ubuntu partition? Will it break grub2?
2. If I can resize the Ubuntu partition leftward, then ultimately my goal is to get rid of the winxp partition all together. Will that be possible? Are there any issues that I should expect, like problems with reconfiguring the hdd primary partition or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I, over time, shrink the Windows
>   partition and enlarge (leftward) the
>   Ubuntu partition?

Yes, use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

> Will it break grub2?

Nope. GParted will **move it** and **resize it**:

[image]

> If I can resize the Ubuntu partition
>   leftward, then ultimately my goal is
>   to get rid of the winxp partition all
>   together. Will that be possible?

Yes. Delete the Windows partition with GParted Live, then expand your Linux volume to fill the space.

> Are there any issues that I should
>   expect, like problems with
>   reconfiguring the hdd primary
>   partition or something like that?

When removing Windows you may still have an entry for it in the GRUB menu. It can be removed from grub.cfg.

Comment: Nice complete answer.